# How I can get date correctly from sql in c#?

Tags: c#, sql

I need to take the time and date when a user posts a comment.

So, I insert the data into the database with this code:

```
SqlDataSource3.InsertCommand = "Insert into [co] (datee, timee) values (@d, @t)";

String dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters.Add("d", dateNow);
String timeNow = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
SqlDataSource3.InsertParameters.Add("t", timeNow);
SqlDataSource3.Insert();
```

But its appears like the photo below:

[image: [photo]]

How I can get the date "yyyy/MM/dd" and time "HH:mm tt"

Comment: Your insert string seems ok. What about the code used to show that data?

Comment: you do not need `[ ]` around the table name perhaps you could get qualify it with `[dbo].[co]` bunt not necessary// can show the table schema of the CO table.. make sure you are casting your variables to the correct type. personally I would create stored procedures and let the code handle the resolving of the variable's datatype.. but there are many ways to skin this cat

Comment: I used datalist to show the data

Comment: String dateNow = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString("yyyy/MM/dd");

Comment: Between the two calls of `DateTime.Now` some time passes. In the end, date may changed. `dateNow = DateTime.Now` - 2017.05.16T23;59:59. `timeNow = DateTime.Now` - 2017.05.17T00:00:00. Oops!

Comment: Have you considered using server side date/time functions (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql or https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_now.asp) - this will have the advantage of the times/dates all being generated by the server & not rely on the client side having correct time/timezone/etc